# Android build works in Eclipse but not with Ant ("already added")

Tags: android, ant, apk, dex

My Android project uses several git submodules marked as Android Libraries. These submodules all have different uses of the ORMlite Android jars and thus have the ORMlite jars included in their `libs` directory. Eclipse handles this situation correctly: it includes the ORMlite jars once during the `dex` processing and generates a valid .apk, but when I run a build via `ant debug`, I get:

```
 [echo] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /home/webedit/.hudson/jobs/xyz/workspace/bin/classes.dex...
[apply] 
[apply] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[apply] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/j256/ormlite/android/AndroidCompiledStatement;
[apply]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:338)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:315)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:266)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:284)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:220)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:176)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:157)
[apply]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:89)
```

Is there any way to have multiple copies of the same JAR sprinkled across multiple libraries? Is there an Ant build setting I can change to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a third Android project with only the ORMlite JAR in it that the two other projects depended on.

Answer (score 4):

i got the same problem using maven because it correctly added the ormlite-core-jarfile, which contains the packages and classes as the core-jar with a few additional classes.

I added an exclusion and now it works

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
                <artifactId>ormlite-android</artifactId>
                <version>4.9</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: my error was: already added: Lcom/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl$1

Comment: the new current version of ormlite seems to not suffer from this problem

Comment: I'm using android studio with gradle and experience the same problem. I added the dependency to the build.gradle via `compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.9'` and the libs got downloaded and linked as expected. But as the jars contain some duplicate classes, I get the `already added: Lcom/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl$1` exception.
Any ideas how to solve it with gradle and build tools  18.0.1?

Comment: @cybergen, can you try a newer version (4.46 is currently the newest) as i mentioned before, i didn't get the error with a newer version. otherwise try excluding the transitive dependency (49.4.7. http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

Comment: @cproinger, oh WOW, now it works! I misunderstood the versioning (my fault). But anyway, the newer version (4.46) contains only the android specific classes in the `ormlite-android.jar` and everything else in the `ormlite-core.jar`. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that all jars in any ./libs folder were included, not just the ones as specified in my eclipse .classpath. So I had some duplicates laying around there. I just needed to clean up my ./libs. You can find out what ant is all including in its "classpath" by running "ant -v debug", somewhere in the top half of the output.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem but with android-support-v4.jar — it was used in referenced project library and app project. Here's the solution

Workaround:
1. Remove file android-support-v4.jar from App/libs
2. In Eclipse add jar referenced to ReferencedProjectLibrary/libs/android-support-v4.jar

It works in Eclipse and Ant too ;)