# How do I setup my Git repositories for Android development in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, git-submodules, egit

I need some help with properly versioning my Android project with Git/Eclipse.
I have no problem setting this up with a single Android project.

However, I am trying to figure out the proper and correct way to set this up, if I add one or more third party Android libraries to my main project (e.g. Facebook SDK).

So currently I am using `git-submodules` to accomplish this, and here's my directory structure:

```
/project/android-main.git
   +--- /project/android-main/facebook-sdk
```

I added `facebook-sdk` as a git-submodule within my `android-main` project.
In Eclipse workspace's `android-main` project, I am seeing the subfolder '`facebook-sdk`'.

Then here comes the **kludge**:
**I have to import 'Existing project' from `/project/android-main/facebook-sdk` as a new project, so that I can reference this project as a library from my `android-main` project.**

In the end, **Eclipse workspace has three references to '`facebook-sdk`'**:

1. The project itself in the workspace.
2. because I added it as a `git-submodule`, it showed up as a folder in `android-main` project.
3. Another folder '`facebook_sdk_src`' is created by the Android SDK plugin in `android-main` project.

This seems to clutter the workspace and the main project, if I add more submodules.
Am I doing it right?
Is there a better way to use Android Libraries as a submodule in Eclipse?

Comment: You current solution bears some resemblance with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091946/android-build-works-in-eclipse-but-not-with-ant-already-added

Comment: Are 1 and 2 different checkouts (modifying files in one doesn't affect the other)? Sounds like 1 is a clone of the remote and 2 is a submodule clone of the local.

Comment: If you have two checkouts, you don't need to have the project itself in the workspace. You can add a submodule directly from a remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of my Android projects are at the same level. Eclipse displays each project twice: in the workspace (workspace/library) and inside projects that reference it (workspace/project/library_src).

You could try making *both* facebook-sdk and android-main submodules so that they're at the same level. Something like this:

```
/project/
   +--- android-main.git
   +--- android-project/
           +--- android-main/
           +--- facebook-sdk/
```

So create a bare repo for your android project (android-main.git). This repo doesn't need to be in your workspace. Then add a subfolder for your code (android-project) and add your submodules.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out EGit (Eclipse Git plugin) does not support submodules too well, so I have to look at other solutions.

Comment: I would not recommend using EGit - it is very half-baked and presents many problems especially in a large environment.

Comment: I think the other solution that works very well is, the terminal :)

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302089/git-plugin-for-eclipse