# What is the standard Git submodule folder structure for Android app?

Tags: java, android, git, git-submodules

I'm developing an Android app that would use a dozens of open source libraries which I plan on importing as submodules. Where should I put these submodules?

Right now I have:

```
/myapp
  /res
  /src
  /libs
  /assets
  ...
  ...
/libs
```

All submodules go under libs. I'm not sure if there is a "best" way to structure your submodules folders but I'd like to know what is the standard out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if there is a "best" way to structure your submodules folders but I'd like to know what is the standard out there.

No standard that I know of.  That [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423468/how-do-i-setup-my-git-repositories-for-android-development-in-eclipse) put all the projects at the same level.

The only standard is more for the [files to ignore in an Android project](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore).