# "already added" exception with ormlite and gradle

Tags: android, exception, gradle, android-studio, ormlite

I'm using android studio 0.2.3 with gradle 0.5 and added the ormlite dependency to the `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.9'
```

Gradle downloaded two jar files: `ormlite-android.jar` and `ormlite-core.jar`. The problem is, that the jar files contain identically named classes. So I get the following well known exception:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl$1;
```

Some other solution for the same problem with maven [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873628/590947), suggesting to exclude the `ormlite-core.jar`. This should work if all classes from `ormlite-core.jar` are included in `ormlite-android.jar` - I didn't check this btw. In that case, I don't understand why the ormlite-core is in this ormlite android dependency package... I'm explicitly adding ormlite-android, as you can see in the snippet above.

But how to exclude the ormlite-core.jar in gradle. Everything I found was for gradle 1.6, but android studio uses gradle 0.5 - or is this just the version of the android gradle wrapper?

.:EDIT:.
To make the dependencies clearer, I add my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.9'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}
```

Why I think there are same classes in the two ormlite libs? ==> See the screenshot.
Aren't the opened packages identical? Even the source is. The only distinct classes I found were `SqliteAndroidDatabaseType` and those in the `com.j256.ormlite.android` package.
[image: Aren't the opened packages identical?]

Comment: Not sure what the problem is but ormlite-android does _not_ include the -core stuff in case there is any question.  The docs are pretty plain about this: http://ormlite.com/docs/getting-started

Comment: I studied the docs already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ormlite-android jar you're using is definitely wrong. My guess is that someone built it incorrectly with ormlite-core exported, which is why you're getting the merge conflicts. If you [look at the source for ormlite-android](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/tree/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite), it isn't supposed to have most of those packages/classes included.

I'm not sure how the ormlite-android versioning works, but it looks like 4.46 is the actual latest version (updated 29-Jul-2013), not 4.9 (updated 26-Jan-2011). I'd recommend using 4.46 instead (that's what works for me) with:

```
'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.46'
```

Comment: I cleaned many times, without success. I edidted my question to make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @cproinger for the answer in [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873628/590947).

WOW, now it works! I misunderstood the versioning (my fault). But anyway, the newer version (4.46) contains only the android specific classes in the `ormlite-android.jar` and everything else in the `ormlite-core.jar`. Great, thanks @cproinger!

Comment: Ah, 6 minutes too slow. I'm glad you found the answer though!